# Attributed string color- Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I have a display like in the picture
[image]

Im getting this from a string str which is like below
[image]

Code I have tried

```
lbl1.text=newStr;
NSString *textxtra = @"Xtra";
NSString *textremove = @"Remove";

NSMutableAttributedString *attrsString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:lbl1.attributedText];

 // search for word occurrence
                    
NSRange range = [lbl1.text rangeOfString:textxtra];
NSRange range1 = [lbl1.text rangeOfString:textremove];
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    [attrsString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor systemGreenColor] range:range];
}
if (range1.location != NSNotFound) {
    [attrsString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:range1];
}

// set attributed text
lbl1.attributedText = attrsString;
```

How to get the string before Xtra (American Cheese) and after Xtra($1) in green color ?

The part before Remove(House Mayo) in red color?
i.e The whole string `American Cheese: Xtra $1` should be in `green color`.
I get the idea to take the string in between \n.
i.e string before Xtra upto \n and after Xtra upto \n
But couldn't understand exactly how to implement

Any ideas/suggestions will be helpful

Comment: You can use `rangeOfString:options:range:` to search for `"\n"`, using the options backwards, and the range to search, being `0, rangeOfXtra.location`. Then, you'll can calculate the range: `(rangeOfN.location, rangeOfXtra.location - rangeOfN.location)`. Repeat for the other one.

Comment: But a quicker solution maybe, would be to split the initial string into an array of `NSString` separated with `"\n"`, create a `NSMutableAttributedString` empty, iterate over each string, and if the line contain one of the world, add the color effect to the whole line, and append to the attributedString.

Comment: @Larme can u post your answer.

Comment: The part before Xtra, before Remove is dynamic from server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but this should do the trick:

```
NSString *initialSting = @"";

NSArray *lines = [initialSting componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

NSMutableArray *attributedLines = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSDictionary *redAttributes =  @{};
NSDictionary *greenAttributes =  @{};

for (NSString *aLine in lines) 
{
    NSAttributedString *aLineAttributedString;
    //Here, you could also check, that the string is like "someString: Xtra someOtherString", because if Xtra is misplaced...
    if ([aLine containsString:@"Xtra"]) 
    {
        aLineAttributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:aLine attributes:greenAttributes];
        //Here, you could also check, that the string is like "someString: Remove someOtherString", because if Remove is misplaced...
    }
    else if ([aLine containsString:@"Remove"]) 
    {
        aLineAttributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:aLine attributes:redAttributes];
    } 
    else 
    {
        aLineAttributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:aLine];
    }
    [attributedLines addObject:aLineAttributedString];
}

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
NSAttributedString *newLine = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"\n"];

if ([attributedLines count] > 0) 
{
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [attributedLines count] - 1; i++) 
    {
        [attributedString appendAttributedString:attributedLines[i]];
        [attributedString appendAttributedString:newLine];
    }
    [attributedString appendAttributedString:[attributedLines lastObject]];
}
```

The logic:
Get an array of NSString for each line with `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:`
Create an array of `NSAttributedString`, that will be populated for each line.
For each line, color it if needed, then add it to the array.
Finally, there is no `componentsJoinedByString:` for `NSAttributedString`, so do a manual for loop to reconstruct the final `NSAttributedString`.